Is $F(u)=\ell(\chi_{[a,u)})$ also right-continuous?

A linear functional $l$ is a linear transformation from a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ to the underlying field of scalars, which we may assume to be the complex numbers, $$\ell: \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{C}$$ (Stein & Shakarchi, Measure Theory, Integration, & Hilbert Spaces, pg. $181$)


Consider $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{C}([a,b])$, the vector space comprising all continuous functions $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $\ell: \mathcal{C}([a,b]) \to \mathbb{R}$ be any linear functional. For $a \leq u < b$, let
$$\chi_{[a,u)}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & a \leq x < u \\ 0 & u \leq x \leq b \end{cases}$$
Then $\chi_{[a,u)}$ is right continuous on $[a,b]$.
Claim: Is it true that
the function $F$ given by $F(u):=\ell(\chi_{[a,u)})$ is also right continuous?
As I've left $\ell$ to be arbitrary, if the claim is true, then showing such would seem to require utilizing the linearity of $\ell$. Intuitively, since $\ell$ is linear, it seems like it should work, but showing that this is the case isn't quite as clear. Stating what we know explicitly, we have at least two tools:

1. $\ell$ is linear $\iff \ell\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\chi_k\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \ell\left(\chi_k\right)$


2. $\chi_{[a,u)}$ is right continuous on $[a,b] \iff$ for each $\alpha \in [a,b], \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \alpha^+} \chi_{[a,u)}(x) = \chi_{[a,u)}(\alpha)$

To show that $F(u)= \ell(\chi_{[a,u)})$ is right continuous, we mean that we must show that for each $u \in [a,b)$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to u^+} F(x) = F(u) = \ell(\chi_{[a,u)})$
So ultimately my question: Is $F(u)$ right continuous? If so, how might I show this?

NOTE: My approach may seem confusing since clearly $\chi_{[a,u]} \not\in \mathcal{C}([a,b])$. The reason for this approach is as such: if I first show that $F$ is right continuous under step functions, then from there, if I want to show that $F$ is right continuous over $f \in \mathcal{C}([a,b])$, the result follows immediately since every continuous function can be approximated by simple functions. Hence, the mention of $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{C}([a,b])$ is not necessary for my question; it merely gives the context within which I'm working.

How is $F$ defined? Your functional $\ell$ is not defined on discontinuous functions. Continuity depends heavily on the topology. Which one are you using?

A potential space where you could be working in is the closure of the step functions in the uniform norm. Also, are you assuming $\ell$ to be continuous? If not, then I am fairly confident that there will be choices where $F$ will be discontinuous. On the other hand, if $\ell$ is continuous, then $F$ might be trivially continuous (depending on the topology).

As stated, we can find $\ell$ such that $F$ won't be right-continuous. As a rule of thumb, general linear functionals on infinite dimensional spaces are horrible.
You do not tell us which space you are working on, but it does not matter too much. For every $q\in (a,b)$ set $f_q=1_{[a,q)}$. Note that we need that $(f_q)_{q\in (a,b)}$ must be contained in the space on which $\ell$ is defined. Furthermore, $(f_q)_{q\in (a,b)}$ are linearly independend and hence we can extend it to a basis $\{f_q\}_{q\in (a,b)}\cup \{ g_\lambda \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$. Finally, we define
$$\ell(h)=\begin{cases} 0,& h=f_q, q\in (a,b)\cap \mathbb{Q}^c,\\ 1,& h=f_q, q\in (a,b)\cap \mathbb{Q}, \\ 
0,& h=g_\lambda.\end{cases}$$
This can be linearly extended and in this case we get
$$F(x)=\ell(f_x)=1_{(a,b)\cap \mathbb{Q}}(x)$$
which is far from being right-continuous.
Now, if you were looking at $\mathcal{H}=L^2([a,b])$ (note that $C([a,b])$ with the standard norm is not a Hilbert space) and $\ell$ was assumed to be continuous, then $F$ will always be continuous. By the Riesz representation theorem, we can can find a function $g\in L^2([a,b])$ such that for all $f\in L^2([a,b])$ holds
$$ \ell(f) = \int_{[a,b]} \overline{g(x)} f(x) dx. $$
With this, $F$ becomes
$$ F(u) = \int_{[a,b]} \overline{g(x)} \chi_{[a,u)}(x)dx $$
which is continuous by the dominated convergence theorem.
